# What is the fastest way to get non-diagonal mirror elements in a matrix that are zero?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Let say there is a matrix as follow:

```
a = np.array([[74,  0,  2],
              [ 0, 73,  8],
              [ 0, 10, 72]])
```

I want to find mirror elements that are zero in both upper and lower triangles and set them to `nan`. E.g. In this case `a[0, 1]` and `a[1, 0]`. I can write a loop like:

```
m = np.zeros((3, 3))
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    for j in range(a.shape[1]):
        if i == j:
            m[i, j] = a[i, j]
            continue
        if (a[i, j] == 0) & (a[j, i] == 0):
            m[i, j] = np.nan
            m[j, i] = np.nan
            continue
        m[i, j] = a[i, j]
        m[j, i] = a[j, i]
print(m)
```

```
[[74. nan  2.]
 [nan 73.  8.]
 [ 0. 10. 72.]]
```

This does the job. But I have millions of these matrices and I am wondering what would be a better and faster approach.

Comment: You could use `m.nonzero(m == 0)` to get the coordinates of all the zero values, then swap the order of the coordinates and look for equality, but honestly I'm not sure that's any better.

Comment: Or maybe `m1 = m[x==0]` / `m2 = np.logical_and(m1, m1.T)` / `m[m2] = np.nan`, although that would also get zeros along the diagonal.

Comment: `np.tril(a) == np.triu(a).T` should get you the matching mirror elements. Then `a==0 `should give you boolean where values are 0. Taking a `and` between the 2 will give you the boolean for the elements you need to replace with nan. check my answer for the code.

Comment: If you have millions of very small matrices, then the cost of Numpy calls will be a problem. It is probably wise to work on all the matrices at the same times in one algorithm (batch computation).

Comment: I agree, all the solutions here are working perfectly, but I have to loop through millions of smart matrices which all the solutions are pretty slow for that.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another alternative, based on my comment suggestion.  Note that the "ndiag" thing is not required if there will never be zeros along the diagonal.

```
import numpy as np

ndiag = 1-np.eye(3)
print(ndiag)

a = np.array( [[74,0,2],[0,73,8],[0,10,72]] ).astype(float)

m = a == 0
print( m )
m = np.logical_and( ndiag, np.logical_and( m, m.T ) )
print( m )
a[m] = np.nan
print( a )
```

Output:

```
[[0 1 1]
 [1 0 1]
 [1 1 0]]
[[False  True False]
 [ True False False]
 [ True False False]]
[[False  True False]
 [ True False False]
 [False False False]]
[[74. nan  2.]
 [nan 73.  8.]
 [ 0. 10. 72.]]
```

Answer (score 3):

I've always had a preference for `triu_indices` and `tril_indices` for this sort of task. The nice thing is that they're just indices, so if all your matrices are the same size, you can cache them once without copying any specific data. The other nice thing is that for a given size `n`, you have that `triu_indices(n, 1)` is the swapped result of `tril_indices(n, -1)` up to some sorting that you don't generally care about.

So if all your matrices are of shape `(n, n)`,

```
rows, cols = np.triu_indices(n, 1)
mask = (a[rows, cols] == a[cols, rows]) & (a[rows, cols] != 0)
a[rows[mask], cols[mask]] = a[cols[mask], rows[mask]] = np.nan
```

Keep in mind that you can't assign `np.nan` to an array unless it's a floating point type. Also, you may get a tiny bit of mileage out of pre-computing `rows[mask]` and `cols[mask]`:

```
rm = rows[mask]
cm = cols[mask]
a[rm, cm] = a[cm, rm] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a completely vectorised approach to solve this -

```
np.where(np.logical_and(np.tril(a) == np.triu(a).T, a==0), np.nan, a)
```

```
array([[74., nan,  2.],
       [nan, 73.,  8.],
       [ 0., 10., 72.]])
```

---

#### Explanation -

Lets see what happens in the first step -

```
np.tril(a) #keeps only the lower triangular, and others become 0

array([[74,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 73,  0],
       [ 0, 10, 72]])

np.triu(a).T #keeps only the upper triangular and others become 0. Then flips it to become lower triangular

array([[74,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 73,  0],
       [ 2,  8, 72]])
```

Equating these will give you the upper triangular part always as True, while lower triangual matrix contains True only for mirror matching elements.

```
np.tril(a) == np.triu(a).T

array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True]])
```

Now, when you take a logical_and of this boolean with the a==0 matrix, only the values where the original matrix had 0 and were mirror elements remain.

```
np.logical_and(np.tril(a) == np.triu(a).T, a==0)

array([[False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False, False, False]])
```

Now you can use `np.where` to replace True values with nan and keep the remaining values intact.

```
np.where(np.logical_and(np.tril(a) == np.triu(a).T, a==0), np.nan, a)

array([[74., nan,  2.],
       [nan, 73.,  8.],
       [ 0., 10., 72.]])
```

Comment: Updated my answer to be much more simpler.